# ubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-i386(i have downloaded it manually)

Tags: 12.04, installation, wubi

please tell me where to put ubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-i386(i have downloaded it manually)
i have mounted the ubuntu iso file on F:

Comment: You need to either burn the ISO to a DVD, or create a bootable USB.  You can use [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/) for DVD, and [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) for a bootable USB.

Comment: any more suggestions

Comment: Did you try any of those suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

To install from a USB stick, just:

1. Download [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/)
2. Run Rufus and select your USB stick as the device
3. Click Start
4. Once Rufus is done, reboot to BIOS on the computer you wish to install on
5. Change the boot order to USB first
6. Plug in your USB if it is not still plugged in and cold reboot your computer
7. The computer should boot straight to Ubuntu, from which you can install as if from a disk

I have tried this process and it worked for me. Also, be sure to make sure your checksums match for your iso.